# stop user input being space or nothing

Tags: javascript, while-loop

How to return true in a while loop if a space (or nothing) is entered from user input prompt.  Can't use NaN as that returns a 0 and I need to allow 0.  Can use x=="" or x==" " but that won't work if 2 (or more) spaces are entered.

Comment: you can use x.trim() == "", in case you want to find n number of spaces.

Comment: yes you are legends.  works nice.  thanks.